# Xcode Cloud: build SDK -> post script create-xcframework -> retrieve file

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

At this moment Xcode Cloud builds our SDK scheme.

What we are interested is running a post-xcodebuild script that will run our custom: "xcodebuild -create-xcframework...." which in turn, will produce the product (file) we want to download and use.

Of course, locally the script works great but we would like to integrate this process in Xcode Cloud CI.
The way I see it, a good solution will be to have the product of the script available for download in the Artifact section inside Xcode Cloud. But, if it can't be done, how can we provide a link to the file after the machine has finished to run the script or does it mean that once the machine has finished the build it deletes everything.

What about Xcode Cloud API ? is there a solution there ?

Perhaps a another workaround would be to add another code to the script that will upload the script's product/file to, for example, S3 so we would have access to it ?
Thank you.